# ETA for RXTX back in Netty 4

Tags: netty, rxtx

There used to be RXTX support in an old Netty 4 branch.

Is there any ETA for having RXTX back in Netty 4?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no"... The "long" as soon as someone finds the time. Feel free to port it back and open a pull request once done ;)